# Dynamic creation of divs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create dynamic divs in a ASP.NET application.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<produkt> produkte = Repository.GetProductsRanged(0, 9).ToList();
}
```

As you can see, there is a of products (10 elements) and I want to put some of there attributes in divs. Every product should have it owns div. How can I do this dynamicaly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a [repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div>
         SomeValue
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind**

```
rep.DataSource=Repository.GetProductsRanged(0, 9).ToList();
rep.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a repeater:

```
foreach (produkt prod in produkte)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes["one"] = "one";
    div.Attributes["two"] = "two";
    this.Form.Controls.Add(div);
}
```